# No internet upon ip change for server 20.04

Tags: networking, server, kvm-virtualization

I re-organized my router setup and everything got a new ip (I am discussing internal ip's here). So, I changed the server's static ip in netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml.

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: no

  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [eno1]
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.2.50/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.1.1]
```

This is where I may have made a mistake, I then kept changing things trying to make it work and forgot how it was when I started and it was working with the other ip. Its strange because all I did was change the previous ip to the new ip originally. Internet did not work after that.

I have KVM installed on this server with another 2 virtual machines. I am hoping someone can help me fix up my netplan file and get things working again.

Comment: Try changing `gateway4:` and `nameservers:` to `192.168.2.1` as this is most likely the new address for your router now.

Comment: Static IP's usually require a reboot to take. Do `sudo netplan generate` and `sudo netplan apply` and `reboot`. You can also remove the dhcp4 lines, as false/no is the default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases, the **gateway** should be on the same sub-net as the **IP** address of the server. Otherwise, data packets can not go through and there will be no connectivity.

Looking at the IP `192.168.2.50/24` and the gateway `192.168.1.1` in your configuration.
They are not on the same sub-net.

I would suggest finding out the correct addresses for both your gateway and nameserver ( most likely the IP of your router) and changing them accordingly in your server's netplan file.

I guess the new address for your router is `192.168.2.1`. If that is correct then you need to changing both the **gateway** and the **nameserver** addresses to `192.168.2.1`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. It worked! Does it matter if I change the Nameservers field?

Comment: @i9pp0 Unless you are planning to only use IP addresses to communicate and no domain names, yes it does matter. If no functioning DNS is provided, domain names will not be resolved thus cannot reach destination machines using domain names.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I thought maybe it would default to ISP DNS or something....